# Bringing together transformations in pandas and TDD practices

Tags: python, pandas, tdd

So I have read [this article on pandas anti-patterns](https://www.aidancooper.co.uk/pandas-anti-patterns/) and in the article it mentions the following: when you want to apply a set of transformation to a dataframe, you should chain them:

```
# Mutation - DON'T DO THIS
df_bad = df.query("runtime > 30 & type == 'SHOW'")
df_bad["score"] = df_bad[["imdb_score", "tmdb_score"]].sum(axis=1)
df_bad = df_bad[["seasons", "score"]]
df_bad = df_bad.groupby("seasons").agg(["count", "mean"])
df_bad = df_bad.droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
df_bad = df_bad.query("count > 10")

# Chaining - DO THIS
df_good = (df
    .query("runtime > 30 & type == 'SHOW'")
    .assign(score=lambda df_: df_[["imdb_score", "tmdb_score"]].sum(axis=1))
    [["seasons", "score"]]
    .groupby("seasons")
    .agg(["count", "mean"])
    .droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
    .query("count > 10")
)
```

However, in Uncle Bob's Clean Code book, it suggests that chaining is not a clean practice, since then you can't really test it via TDD.

In general, how can one apply TDD to sets of transformations in pandas? I don't have a clue how I would bring the two concepts together besides doing, apparently, an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In my own personal experience, I would say that in your particular scenario it depends on what you are aiming to test:

1. Test individual transformation steps that are subsequently applied to a pandas DataFrame
2. Test the final output of your transformation pipeline steps

For scenario 1, it might make sense to use the first structure, if you want to validate the integrity of the output of every transformation step.

For scenario 2, chaining would also allow you to apply TDD principles to your code, but it would not necessarily be considered a unit test, as it would be closer to an integration test, if you consider every transformation step of the pipeline as a single unit of functionality.

I would suggest checking the concept of [Test-Driven Data Analysis (TDDA)](https://tdda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.02/) to help you with implementing a TDD approach for data pipelines in general. In the provided library reference you also have a section dedicated to Pandas. I also recommend the following YouTube videos:

- [Test-Driven Data Analysis - Nick Radcliffe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw6P6VFPo24)
- [Raoul-Gabriel Urma, Kevin Lemagnen: Adv. Software Testing for Data Scientists | PyData London 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTj6T0QdHHM&t=4432s)